# Cosa vuol dire "moschito" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Riecco il pane abbrustolito con la marmellata di fichi della signora Viense; ecco il bus con le pulegge avanzare in un'atipica via Marconi innevata; ecco Remo lavorando troppo di manopole tramazzare col **moschito** nel punto di via Calatafimi dove  salivano i campi, e il croscio delle risate pervase di gioia nel constatare il danno nullo dell'incidente.

L'incidente di cui parla questa frase ha luogo negli anni 40 o 50.
Sul [*Vocabolario degli accademici della Crusca*](http://www.lessicografia.it/Controller?lemma=TRAMAZZARE&rewrite=1) ho visto che "tramazzare" significa "stramazzare". Il mio dubbio è, però, sul significato del termine "moschito". L'ho trovato sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI10/00000997.jpg), ma non riesco a capire a quale accezione possa corrispondere l'uso che se ne fa nel passaggio sopra citato. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: @Gio:  Ah, grazie: l'ho trovato anche [qui](https://books.google.es/books?id=0mdXAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=%22+moschito+bicicletta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tratta probabilmente di  [moschito o mosquito](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/M/moschito.html) nel seguente senso:

> Nome commerciale, che costituisce marchio registrato, di un motore applicabile alle biciclette, con trasmissione a rullo.

([Sabatini Coletti](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/M/mosquito.shtml))

In sostanza  si tratta di una [bicicletta motorizzata](https://www.google.com/search?q=mosquito%20bicicletta&safe=strict&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&prmd=sinv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia04SWk4vnAhWJyqQKHUZfBWMQ_AUoAnoECA0QAg&biw=768&bih=915#imgrc=uRyCQDzKBvkAbM), in voga negli anni del secondo dopoguerra.